# How to close and reopen shell with a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, anaconda, conda, restart

So I am trying to install conda on a linux server. For this, I am running a bash script as a root user and I have made a new user which is going to install conda. The new user is "ags". Added below are lines from my shell script.

```
echo "Getting the conda installer"
su - ags -c "wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O /${install_directory}/ags/miniconda.sh"
echo "Installing conda"
su - ags -c "bash /${install_directory}/ags/miniconda.sh -b -p /${install_directory}/ags/miniconda"


###ERROR PART UNDERNEATH ####
su - ags -c "/${install_directory}/ags/miniconda/condabin/conda init bash"

su - ags -c "export ARCGISHOME=/${install_directory}/ags/arcgis/server; conda activate
```

However, my **output** is asking me to restart shell:

```
root@my_server:~# su - ags -c "/data/ags/miniconda/condabin/conda init bash"
no change     //data/ags/miniconda/condabin/conda
no change     //data/ags/miniconda/bin/conda
no change     //data/ags/miniconda/bin/conda-env
no change     //data/ags/miniconda/bin/activate
no change     //data/ags/miniconda/bin/deactivate
no change     //data/ags/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     //data/ags/miniconda/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     //data/ags/miniconda/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     //data/ags/miniconda/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     //data/ags/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     //data/ags/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
modified      //data/ags/.bashrc

==> For changes to take effect, close and re-open your current shell. <==

root@my_server:~# su - ags -c "conda activate"
-sh: 1: conda: not found
```

Is there a way to restart my shell (ags) and still keep the script running after that?

Comment: What are you expecting `conda activate` to do in this context? Is there more to the script you are trying to run?

Comment: Yes after this I will be making a new conda environment and install some services on it. Conda activate should just activate the base environment.

Comment: In such programmatic cases, that is usually better done with [a YAML environment definition](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually) for the environment, e.g., `/data/ags/miniconda/condabin/conda env create -f environment.yaml`.

Answer (score 4):

Conda defines `conda activate` as a shell function and `conda init` puts code in init files (here `.bashrc`) to ensure the function gets defined at the start of interaction shell sessions. An alternative to restarting the session is to instead `source ~/.bashrc`.

It might be worth noting that a (usually minor) concern with manually re-sourcing an init file in an already active section is that some of the code in `.bashrc` could be non-idempotent (i.e., running it multiple times has a different effect than running it just once). [Fatih Arslan has a nice blog post](https://arslan.io/2019/07/03/how-to-write-idempotent-bash-scripts/) with tips about writing bash scripts that are idempotent by design.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It works fine when I am in the terminal as ags user. However since I am trying to run the entire script as root, I am getting this error:
Commad: 

`root@my_machine:~# su - ags -c "source ~/.bashrc"`

Ouput:
`-sh: 1: source: not found`
@merv